# Как избавиться от pN аргументов в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
*Показываю на примере RecyclerView* 
При импорте функций класса создается функция в таком виде:
**p0 и p1** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не имея логические названия переменным как было раньше
**holder и position** (а не как теперь p0 и p1)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как решить проблему? И почему она возникла?**

Answer (score 2):

Решилось все очень просто если добавить библиотеку в Gradle: 
`implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'`

Будут аргументы при имплементе подставляться корректные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Остается вопрос к разработчика Android Studio, почему вы не смогли сделать лучше? )

Comment: Совсем обленились девелоперы, код за них пиши и еще переменные обзывай как надо :) Ну не было у AS доступа к исходникам, а из байткода все не вытянуть.